# How can I create customized builtins in Jena?

Tags: java, eclipse, sparql, jena, rule

I just wondering how I can create new custom builtins for Jena. I know that for this purpose it should be used both the class "BaseBuiltin" and the class "BuiltinRegistry" (but how ?).

I have also found out a plugin for Eclipse which is called "SADL" but I am not sure if I can use if for this purpose. If I can...which method is better and why ?

Could anyone of you explain me which way I should take ?

Cheers!

Comment: Have you seen the [writing Jena built-ins](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12139978/1281433) question (it's not a great question, and the answer doesn't help all that much, in my opinion, but it's relevant).

Comment: What do you want your builtin to do?  They're not too hard to implement, but some specific requirements would make it easier to craft an example.

Comment: Also, have you looked at the source to any of the builtins in Jena that extend BaseBuiltin.  E.g., [addOne](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.jena/jena-core/2.7.3/com/hp/hpl/jena/reasoner/rulesys/builtins/AddOne.java)?

Answer (score 1):

In a [follow-up to a later question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23270901/2528639), I provide code demonstrating the answer to this question, as well.

I've duplicated it here for the sake of people who need a quick reference. This builtin has the name `example` and delegates the majority of it's functionality to [`BaseBuiltin`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/reasoner/rulesys/builtins/BaseBuiltin.html) as per [writing Jena builtin-ins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139978/writing-jena-built-ins) and the [Official Documentation](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/#RULEextensions). Thanks to JT for the reference to his previous question.

```java
BuiltinRegistry.theRegistry.register( new BaseBuiltin() {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "example";
    }
    @Override
    public void headAction( final Node[] args, final int length, final RuleContext context ) {
        System.out.println("Head Action: "+Arrays.toString(args));
    }
} );
```